# Display data from all previous activity to one activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to ask, if i have more than one activity that need to past another activity, how? from the code below, i already pass the data from activity A and display to DisplayActivity, but now i want to add another activity which is activity A and B and all data from them is pass to DisplayActivity. COde represent Activity A. Code 2 represent DisplayActivity

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);

            intent1.putExtra("first_name",edt1.getText().toString());
            intent1.putExtra("last_name",edt2.getText().toString());
            intent1.putExtra("date_of_birth",edt3.getText().toString());
            //startActivity(intent1);

            startActivityForResult(intent1,1);



  Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent2.getExtras();
    String first = bundle.getString("first_name");
    String last = bundle.getString("last_name");
    String dob = bundle.getString("date_of_birth");

    txt5.setText(":  "+first.toString()+" "+last.toString());
    txt7.setText(":  "+dob.toString());
```

Comment: using this way only you can pass data from other activities to display activity and another method is you can create a model class and save the information in it and then access it in your display activity

Comment: Intent passes data when you run the activity for example:- if you open activity A and then go to activity B, then it will show data, however if you don't open A or B you app will crash as display activity is not getting intent from the activity which is not started.
If you want to save data from both activities and use it afterwards without the need to launch both of them, use sharedPrerences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save your all the data in shared preference and retrieve the data where you want.

create a AppPreference class and create some getter and setter according to your need the save your data in shared preference and get where you want.

AppPreference class :-

```
public class AppPreference {
    private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;

    public static String getFirstName(Context ctx) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return mPrefs.getInt("first_name", "");
    }

    public static void setFirstName(Context ctx, Integer value) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putInt("first_name", value);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

to set values :-

```
AppPreference.getFirstName(activity, edt1.getText().toString());
```

and to get values :-

```
String firstName = getFirstName(this);
```

Comment: As i newbies in this programming. can i know one example that same as my case using SharedPreferences

Comment: create a class in your project and set name AppPreference

Comment: and create some gatter and satter in your class

Comment: i have updated my answer according to save your first name

Comment: if it helps you appreciate the answer